# How can I assign the integers in an input like 1.2.3 to variables in C++?

Tags: c++

Here is an example of what I mean.

Input: `10.20.50`

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 50
```

Comment: `int a; int b; int c; char dot1; char dot2; cin >> a >> dot1 >> b >> dot2 >> c;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to store the input in a string or char[] and then iterate over the string or char[] and write some code that will identify the separate parts of the input and convert them to ints using stoi().

this would work but just an example (and i think it will not print the final number unless the input is ended with "." but this should give you an idea of what you could do.

```
std::string i = "";
std::cin >> i;

std::string buffer = "";
for (auto c : i)
{
    if (c != '.')
    {
        buffer += c;
    }
    else
    {
        int num = std::stoi(buffer);
        buffer = "";
        std::cout << num << ", ";
    }
}
```